# need appium command for 'refresh source & screenshot' in python

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, python-appium

Does anyone know how I can include 'refresh source & inspector' as a command for a native android or ios app in an appium python script?

I'm trying to automate a test on appium and sometimes screen rendering does not work after an element has been clicked. So I was thinking of inserting delay and 'refresh source' as commands at these locations so I don't have to manually do it every time. Unfortunately, the refresh click is not included as a step by the recorder and so it does not auto-generate an equivalent command for it in the recorder. I've found a command to refresh a web page on other forums (self.driver.refresh()) but not for an app. I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me here.

[image]

Comment: sometimes screen rendering does not work after an element has been clicked...

Does this happen even without appium when you use the app normally?

Comment: No, the app on the phone opens normally. I've observed that, during app navigation, if an interface opens spontaneously appium does not have a problem rendering it. But if the app takes time to load a new interface and most often, when a loading screen is displayed, appium does not render it after it's fully loaded. I have to manually refresh the source screen to see the interface. It seems like appium stops refreshing the screen after a set period of time (usually a couple of seconds). Is there anyway to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some elements cover the elements you want to find. I also meet something like this. In my case, a tip element covers the others, and I try clicking that tip element and it is hidden, after that, elements being covered now can be found.